# Oracle Sql Query for getting html page side menu items from database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

**Table name:**

```
 SERVICEID     SERVICENAME       SERVICELINK     PARENTID     ORDERVALUE    
 ------------  ----------------  --------------  -----------  ------------- 
 7             Add Event         addEvent.do     2            1             
 8             MANAGE REMAINDER  #               3            1             
 9             ADD REMAINDER     addRem.do       3            2             
 10            MODIFY            modifyRem.do    8            1             
 1             HOME              #               0            1             
 2             EVENT             #               0            2             
 3             REMAINDER         #               0            3             
 4             MY PROFILE        #               0            4             
 5             LOGIN DETAILS     #               0            5             
 6             ABOUT US          #               0            6
```

**and desired result is**

```
HOME

EVENT
   ADD EVENT

REMAINDER
   ADD REMAINDER
   MANAGE REMAINDER
       MODIFY

MY PROFILE

LOGIN DETAILS

ABOUT US
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 with CTE (SERVICEID,PARENTID,SERVICENAME,[level]) as (
   select SERVICEID,PARENTID,SERVICENAME,0 as [level] 
   from page_items where PARENTID=0
   union all
   select P1.SERVICEID,P1.PARENTID,P1.SERVICENAME,P2.[level]+1 as [level] 
   from page_items P1, CTE P2
 where p2.SERVICEID=p1.PARENTID)
select lpad('      ',[level])||SERVICENAME from CTE
```

Comment: CTE is common table expression. I think CTE is available in Oracle from 11g. Do you have Oracle 11g installed ?

Comment: The Oracle `WITH` clause is supported in Oracle 10g. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm